# Trying to change the content of a page without reloading after passing a value to a variable on submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Retrieving data from an API using Php. This my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])) 
{
    $login = 'something';
    $password = 'something';
    $query = urlencode( $_POST[ "search"]);
    $url = 'something' . $query;;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login . ":" . $password);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    $output = json_decode($result, true);

    foreach ($output['response']['customers']['customer'] as $r)
        {
            $inner = $r['lifetime_points'];   
        };
 } 
  else 
 {
      echo ("No search query has received");
 }
?>
```

Html code:

```
 <div id="get_text" >
<div><em>CHECK YOUR POINTS</em></div>
<div ><em>Enter mobile number</em></div>
<form action='' method='POST' id='search-form'>
<div> 
<input type='search' name='search' id="sub1" />
</div>
<div>
<button type="submit"  id="sub" >Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<div id="show_text" >
<div><em>YOUR CURRENT POINTS ARE </em></div>
<form action='' method='GET' id='result'>
<div> 
<input type='text' name='points' value="<?php echo $inner; ?>"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

So through AJAX I'm initially displaying my div tag with ID=get_text in which I'm retrieving data from an API and storing it in a variable after pressing submit. After pressing submit I'm hiding the div tag with id=get_text and displaying the div tag with id=show_text.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show_text").hide();
    $("#sub").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'aristocracy-test.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data : $("#get_text").serialize(), //pass your form elements as key-value pairs
            success: function (response) {
                $("#show_text").show();
                $("#get_text").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
 </script>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the value is not getting passed to div tag with ID=show_text after pressing the submit button on hiding the div tag with id=get_text. There isn't anything wrong with my API code, as I have tested it before implementing AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to set the response to the div after showing the div .
Please add `$("#show_text").html(response);` after showing the div.

If you want to show the result in textbox . Use

```
$('input[name="textboxname"]').val( response ) ;
```

then your code will be like.

```
success: function (response) {
                $("#show_text").show();
                $('input[name="textboxname"]').val(response) ;
                $("#get_text").hide();
            }
```

Comment: The AJAX call works but I'm still not able to retrieve the variable value from my API. Instead the word 'response' is being displayed in the input box.

Comment: can you please try this $('input[name="textboxname"]').val(response) ; quotes will make it string value

Comment: Did you got any response from ajax call. You can check it through browser console . I didnt find any echo in php code .

Comment: I did try that. That's when I got the output as response in my textbox. I'm unable to get my variable value

Comment: Please confirm the ajax post data and response first.

Comment: I haven't received any response from ajax call.

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. - this is what I'm getting now in my console log

Comment: Can you check again after set the async option to true -  Like                         url: 'aristocracy-test.php',                                                                                   async: true,

Comment: I tried that. So now for some reason it's echoing my entire footer code in the text box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139495/discussion-between-user1752065-and-navomi-shetty).

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting in your div with id show_text because you did not insert the new data in it :

You need to call `$("#show_text").html(response);` in order to set new data something like:

```
    success: function (response) {
        $("#show_text").show();
        $("#show_text").html(response);
        $("#get_text").hide();
    }
});
```

Also it will remove anything in that div so :

```
<div id="show_text" >
<div><em>YOUR CURRENT POINTS ARE </em></div>
<form action='' method='GET' id='result'>
<div> 
<input type='text' name='points' value="<?php echo $inner; ?>"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

becomes :

```
<div id="show_text" >
    //HERE WILL BE YOUR NEW DATA WHICH CAME FROM AJAX
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

You are not sending proper data in your ajax params:

```
data : $("#get_text").serialize(),
```

This wont do.

change it to :

```
data:{
search : $('#sub1').val()
}
```

Comment: No that doesn't work either, I've tried it before. I just get the error 'No search query has received' and my page repeats itself when I try that.

Comment: Tried implementing the update but the AJAX call still isn't working properly even though I'm able to retrieve the value now.  Both the get_text and show_text div's are being displayed and the page content gets repeated twice.

Comment: I hope you have a separate php file to which your ajax request goes.
Secondly you may try clearing your current html with blank before setting the new HTML like: `$("#show_text").html("");` and then `$("#show_text").html(response);`

Comment: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead[Learn More]  jquery.min.js:1
TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function[Learn More]  aristocracy-test:250:5
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.  jquery.min.js:5:1711

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139499/discussion-between-shakti-phartiyal-and-navomi-shetty).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `$("#show_text").html(response);` in your ajax success method.

Or perhaps you should try this `$('input[name=points]').val(response);`

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your Data posted to server ,Data Returned from server in Browser console .

[image]